# embedding Google My Business reviews onto a webpage

Tags: google-api, embed

Before Google+ got shut down I was able to embed reviews from my Google+ business page directly into my website by using the following code:

```
<div class="g-post" data-href="https://plus.google.com/+myCompanyName/posts/C5mXxBfvuyQ"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

The link in the data-href attribute was obtained directly from the Google+ my business page.

Now that Google+ is no longer, the Google my business page provides a differently formatted link for reviews such as:

```
 https://business.google.com/reviews/l/13034364536743825118/r/AIe9_BFhqAtkXvUqdYNeMuBBGjaAo-4Nzsp8GqZodh3JinpksaIs5fbp68A98KcYqF2nBVn5d98tYmQEc0S_NHIm8awwzKlOh216MBgrXUXucioaxZb60DA
```

When I place the new link into my old code it does not work and I receive the following error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Does anyone know the way to embed My Business reviews now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this the best answer I could find was located here:

[Link How To Show Google Reviews On Website](https://www.tutorialswebsite.com/how-to-add-or-embed-google-review-on-your-website/)

It's much more technical than it used to be, but I suppose that's expected...lol

Answer (score -2):

There is a widget for WordPress I recently reviewed that does display your Google My Business reviews realy nicely and enables you to use your own css styles
Its called "Google Reviews Widget"

https://richplugins.com/documentation